# Form isn't wrapping in the correct class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing some code that hides and displays a different form depending on whether the user wants to login or register. However for some reason my form isn't displaying in the html in between the `<form class="login-inputs">` , its doesn't even appear in the HTML doc. Can anyone see why?

```
<div class="col-md-3">

    <button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-default login hidden">Login</button>
    <button type="button" id="register" class="btn btn-default register">Register</button>
    <form class="login-inputs hidden">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use hidden, it's a class in Bootstrap 3 that hides all the time whether or not jQuery is used since it uses !important. Use another class, perhaps make one up based on a cookie or some other means.

Comment: the form isn't getting wrapped in the form div tags, the hidden isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hidden class.

media screen element "on" and "off" class:

```
/* For Phone device */
.visible-xs{
   display: block !important;
}
.hidden-xs{
   display: none !important;
}
/* For Phone device End */

@media (min-width: 768px){
   .visible-sm{
       display: block !important;
}
  .hidden-sm{
       display: none !important;
}

}
@media (min-width: 992px){
   .visible-md{
      display: block !important;
}
   .hidden-md{
      display: none !important;
}

}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .visible-lg{
       display: block !important;
}
    .hidden-lg{
       display: none !important;
}
}
```

Just use the class. This CSS already have bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Christina, Sorry for the spelling mistake.